# Cannot get past password section of login. Can do guest session though

Tags: startup

When switching on my PC I get to password and background photo. No icons or anything. I have attempted the Ctrl+Alt+F1 route, but this did not work.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I am an electronic peasant so please help with that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Which Desktop are you using? What's your graphic hardware specs?

If you are using Unity Desktop, check this link  [Unity doesn't load, no launcher no dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Where, as [@Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) says (Answer taken directly)

> 1. Try to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
> This may not work but you can try right clicking on the desktop and selecting "Open terminal here." Otherwise, you may need to change to a "hard" terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
>
> 2. Install compizconfig-settings-manager by running
>
>     sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
>
> 3. Then run it with this:
>
>     DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
>
>  The first part tells the terminal which display you want it to load on (otherwise it won't have a clue).
>
> 4. If you switched to a TTY in step 1, switch back to the graphical server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes).
> There there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager waiting for you.
>
> 5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. You will be asked "Ubuntu Unity Plugin requires the plugin OpenGL. Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Enable OpenGL"
> 6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to the terminal and running sudo reboot.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ask ubuntu. Is better to wrte the steps on your answer so, if the link stops being avalble, the answer is still an answer. :)

Comment: is it fine if i copy paste his answer and give his name, profile link and answer link?

Comment: I've edited a bit your answer to make it more beautful to read :)